What is the best way to have instance parameters in a postshap attribute?
I am building a PostSharp attribute that is meant to create a (different) cache for each method it annotates.
I therefore need non-static, instance parameter to contain values:
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<Task<object>>>();;

this however gets me
Cannot serialize the aspects: Cannot find a serializer for type 'System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`

so I annotated my cache with [PNonSerialized]
but now, my _cache was getting null pointer exceptions because (I assume) some deserialization occurred, thwarting my _cache initialization. I am not certain when and why PostSharp has to serialize/deserialize. I managed to circumvent the problem by doing
      private void InitializeCache()
      {
          if (_cache == null)
          {
              _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<Task<object>>>();
          }
      }

      // This method is called after deserialization to re-initialize non-serialized fields
      public override void RuntimeInitialize(MethodBase method)
      {
          base.RuntimeInitialize(method);
          InitializeCache();
      }

but it feels I'm doing something overly complicated, so I'd like to ask the community if there are better ways to achieve what I essentially want, which is to instantiate a different object per PostSharp attribute and keep it in memory.

Aspects are instantiated during compilation. The aspect instances are serialized into the assembly and deserialized at runtime.
What you do is not incorrect. You can skip the first initialization of the _cache field, because the value will not be used anyway.
You can also move the cache to a service, and consume it, but that may make your solution unnecessarily complex. https://doc.postsharp.net/il/custompatterns/aspects/testing/consuming-dependencies
To make things easier, you may use the PostSharp Caching library instead. It solves all problems like generating cache keys, cache invalidation, cache dependencies, and others. https://doc.postsharp.net/il/caching
If you're creating a new project, I'd recommend using Metalama instead. That is a successor of PostSharp with a better user experience. And it includes the caching library as well.
